# MYSQL query totals not correct

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm making a query that gets all companies for all different size types. 
My Query looks like this:

```sql
SELECT
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM companies 
    WHERE CONCAT(Allin + Basis + Entry + 3CXusers) > 4 
    AND CONCAT(Allin + Basis + Entry + 3CXusers) < 11 
    AND YEAR = 2018 AND Period = 12 
  ) AS mini,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM companies 
    WHERE CONCAT(Allin + Basis + Entry + 3CXusers) > 9 
    AND CONCAT(Allin + Basis + Entry + 3CXusers) < 51 
    AND YEAR = 2018 AND Period = 12 
  ) AS small,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM companies 
    WHERE CONCAT(Allin + Basis + Entry + 3CXusers) > 49 
    AND CONCAT(Allin + Basis + Entry + 3CXusers) < 251 
    AND YEAR = 2018 AND Period = 12 
  ) AS medium,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM companies 
    WHERE CONCAT(Allin + Basis + Entry + 3CXusers) > 249
    AND YEAR = 2018 AND Period = 12 
  ) AS large,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM companies 
    WHERE CONCAT(Allin + Basis + Entry + 3CXusers) > 4 
    AND YEAR = 2018 AND Period = 12 
  ) AS total
FROM companies 
LIMIT 1
```

The results I get are:

```
| mini | small | medium | large | total | 
|  133 |  224  |   58   |   5   |  400  |
```

Can someone please explain why I get `400` instead of `420` as total?
As you can see I select all companies that have a size of more than 4.
All sizes I select have more than 4 as size, but why do I get a total of 400?

This is really odd.

My `SQL` structure looks like this:

```
| company_id | Year | Period | Allin | Basis | Entry | 3CXusers |  
| 999        | 2018 | 12     | 34    | 56    | 12    | 0        | // example row
```

I expect to get this result:

```
| mini | small | medium | large | total | 
|  133 |  224  |   58   |   5   |  420  |
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected (matching) result. (As formatted text, not images.) And take a look at [mcve].

Comment: You can try to remove the `CONCAT` (just the `CONCAT`). You can sum all the columns simply with `+`.

Comment: tried but didn't work

Comment: Those subqueries aren't needed. Just use `case` expressions to do conditional aggregation-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you check your limit for sizes, you will see that there are overlaps. For example in the first one you have 4 < sum < 11 and in the second one 9 < sum < 51. 10 will be shared by both of them. Because of overlaps, the total is different.

Answer (score 1):

Incorporating the comments / answers suggested above:

```sql
WITH cte(MyVal) AS (
  SELECT CONCAT(Allin + Basis + Entry + 3CXusers) AS MyVal
  FROM companies
)
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN MyVal > 4 AND MyVal < 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS mini,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MyVal > 9 AND MyVal < 51 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS small,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MyVal > 49 AND MyVal < 251 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS medium,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MyVal > 249 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS large,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MyVal > 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total -- Must come after "mini" check
FROM cte
WHERE YEAR = 2018 
AND Period = 12
```

It's a little easier this way to see the range overlap.  It would have been cleaner to use `BETWEEN` but this is inclusive and your query ranges are exclusive.